# Matlab: Efficient way of counting non-zero numbers along the boundary of an array

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, count, particles

I have an array whose image looks as shown below. The values in the array represent number of particles at each pixel/grid. I want to calculate distribution of non-zero particles along the periphery/boundary (*periphery/boundary refers to the distribution of farthest points from center*) ***where non-zero particles exist***. As an output from this, I would like to obtain:

> 1) # of non-zero particles along the periphery/boundary, and
>
> 2) # of pixels/grids where those particles reside

Any quick/efficient way of doing this?

[image]

**EDIT 1: Snapshot Describing the Example of a Boundary**
The boundary line traces the non-zero particles.
[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the terminology here.  Could you perhaps show a simple 5x5 example matrix and what the desired output would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a matrix `M` of particle counts, this will get you a mask in `Mb` of the boundary as it has been defined by the question,

```
% define particle count matrix and find non-zero locations
M = randi(5,10,10)-1
[nr,nc] = size(M);
[pRows,pCols] = find(M);

% identify locations that compose the "boundary" line
boundCoords = [accumarray(pCols,pRows',[nc 1],@min)', ...
               accumarray(pCols,pRows',[nc 1],@max)', ...
               1:nr 1:nr; ...
               1:nc 1:nc, ...
               accumarray(pRows,pCols',[nr 1],@min)', ...
               accumarray(pRows,pCols',[nr 1],@max)'];
boundCoords = unique(boundCoords','rows');
boundCoords(any(boundCoords==0,2),:)=[]; %' remove possible (unlikely) zeros

% create a mask representation of the boundary line
Mb = false(size(M));
Mb(sub2ind(size(Mb),boundCoords(:,1),boundCoords(:,2))) = true
```

That is what I understand you want your boundary mask to look like.  The number of pixels that make up the boundary is

```
numBorderPix = sum(Mb(:))
```

The number of particles on those border points is then

```
numBorderParticles = sum(M(Mb))
```

**NOTE: This solution will ensure that *each point on the boundary line has a non-zero particle count*.**

Comment: I have a related question. What if I want to find three different boundaries, which are - 1) one with a maximum number of particle counts, 2) one with a minimum number of particle counts, and 3) one with 'x%' number of particle counts of maximum (#1)? Let me know if you understand or I should make a different question for this. Thanks!

Comment: @Pupil Best to post a new question.

Comment: Here's the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476463/matlab-efficient-way-of-finding-shortest-perpendicular-distance-between-two-dif).

Comment: @chappjc I don't know if you have checked out the new question. But I think it would be easy to modify your solution to the new aspects (two ways of defining the boarder) and getting the least square distance between the two mask.

Answer (score 1):

The periphery `peri` for logical indexing of your matrix `M` is

```
peri = true(25);
peri(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = false;
```

Then, the particle counts `n` in the periphery are `n = M(peri)`. (1) The total number of particles along the boundary is `sum(n)`. (2) The number of pixels where they reside is `sum(n > 0)`.

Comment: Please see the sketch under edit above which describes the boundary I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

-I came up with this algorithm for your problem.

-The details of what you want are not 100% clear so that may not compute exactly what you want.

-The explanation is in the comments

```
A=full(sprand(10,10,0.9));

crossKernel=[0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 1 0]; %% neighbor kernel
isBorder = (conv2(ones(size(A)),crossKernel,'same')~=5); %% find pixels on border
isZeroOnBorder = isBorder & (A==0); %% find zeros on border
%%% the pixels on the new border are...
isNewBorder = (conv2(double(isZeroOnBorder),crossKernel,'same')... %% next to a zero on border
              | isBorder )... %% or on the border of the matrix
              & (~isZeroOnBorder); %% and are not zeros on border
newBorderLength=nnz(isNewBorder) %% counting and obtaining result
```